# Should golf questions be a CW and why?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, community-wiki

I thought CW was for making only 1 answer per language, but on SO I saw again and again, that question had two or more answers of the same language.

1. Should we keep CW-checkbox tradition? If it needs moderators' attention, I can imagine, how big new portion of flags it will be after opening this site.
2. What exactly a purpose of CW in golf is?
3. If we will keep tradition, should we merge same language posts into post with >1 solutions?

Comment: Sorry, what is CW?

Comment: @KevinCox Community Wiki

Answer (score 18):

1. I don't believe we have any need for CW on this site.
2. CW made sense on SO to stop rep hores, but since code golf is the core focus of this site I don't think there is a purpose.
3. Definitely not.

Comment: +1, 100% agree.

Answer (score 13):

No, golf questions should not be CW. Code golf is the raison d'etre for this site, and if we CW'd golf questions, nobody would get any rep for anything useful.

On Stack Overflow, CW for code golf was used because it wasn't a "real" question on SO, and people felt that it'd be better for people to get rep only for answers to real questions. On this site, code golf is indeed "real".

Answer (score 2):

I just posted [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python/55), which could be an example of where CW could be useful here (assuming we accept it as on-topic).