# Why is this question marked community wiki?

Tags: discussion, support

[Anagram Code Golf!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/anagram-code-golf)

Why?  No other code golf questions seem to be :(

[image]

Related: [Should golf questions be a CW and why?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/should-golf-questions-be-a-cw-and-why)

> I don't believe we have any need for CW on this site.

> No, golf questions should not be CW. Code golf is the raison d'etre for this site, and if we CW'd golf questions, nobody would get any rep for anything useful.

Comment: Another question falls victim of auto-CW: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/trolling-homework-questions-sorting :(

Answer (score 3):

Too many answers :(

[Why made community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71644/why-made-community-wiki)

Comment: Well that's a really obnoxious feature...

Comment: Yeah can't we remove that for code golf, I mean loads of these questions are going to generate tons of answers.

Comment: @Tom: Has been semi-removed (the limits have been raised) by now.