# Please raise or remove CW limits on Code Golf SE site

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, community-wiki

Please kindly raise or remove CW limits on [Code Golf SE site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com)

1. Raise or Remove CW Conversion because of too many edits
2. Raise or Remove CW Conversion because of too many answers
3. Please allow current moderators of Code Golf SE to revert CW back to normal.

Comment: You should back this up with evidence that the current situation is harming the site.

Comment: @ChrisF There was a [recent incident](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/236/why-is-this-question-marked-community-wiki) of conversion, so the problem does exist. That said, this should've been asked on Code Golf's per-site-meta, since it affects only them.

Comment: @ChrisF, here is the one post related to Jeff's recent tweet - http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/statuses/45354104700157952

Comment: YOU might want to accept [the answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1449/2775)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler, Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hooray, [automatic CW has been completely removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947/180276) network-wide!

This is no longer a problem. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!

Comment: In that case, I'd like to ask that the CW get reversed on my [2014 question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/produce-the-number-2014-without-any-numbers-in-your-source-code).

Answer (score 18):

For now, we raised the limits as follows:

- Editing your own post:  100
- Number of answers:  60

If this doesn't suffice, we'll look at changing it again.

Comment: Thanks for your quick support @Nick and SO Team, I guess we currently have around 50 active members, so Number of answers limit : 60 may be OK for now, but might ask again, when more active users or when it become the case.

Comment: Was not enough: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/trolling-homework-questions-sorting

Comment: Yes please, change it again. I'd be in favor of removing it entirely actually, since this site naturally garners lots of answers.

Comment: @Victor I cleared the wiki, new limit is 500 but I only reversed wiki on the first page of answers...will need the mods to clear wiki on the rest as I'm on a mobile phone and it's fairly painful to do. I'm flagging it for them now

Answer (score 17):

I'm in favour of removing the limit entirely (or setting it to a crazy number like 2147483647), and removing the CW bit for all questions previously affected. Just throwing in my vote. ;-)

Comment: Completely agree. The auto-CW attacked again in the [code trolling question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/trolling-homework-questions-sorting).

Answer (score 2):

I'll note that the [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/anagram-code-golf) that seems to have [sparked this request](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236/why-is-this-question-marked-community-wiki) generated [two](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/anagram-code-golf/1349#1349) very similar [answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/anagram-code-golf/1349#1349) in Ruby in the last 12 hours, and they were both longer than the [existing Ruby answer using the same strategy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/anagram-code-golf/1302#1302).

I'm the last person to say *"You can't play if you're not going to win."*, but is that really helpful or interesting?

Sheesh! Since then there has been [another like them](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/anagram-code-golf/1372#1372).

Comment: Sounds like a good reason to downvote those answers, not to punish everyone for there being too many answers.