# Upvote on answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I had an up-vote on my answer here: [I need a program where the user inputs an array of doubles and the program outputs the array sorted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/trolling-homework-questions-sorting/16331#16331).

My question is why did my reputation not go up?  It is listed in my reputation list, but my rep did not go up, and it doesn't say it did, it is just listed.

I really wouldn't care, but I do not have access to many features that I like on Stack Overflow, and it is hard enough to earn rep as it is!

Comment: As @Victor mentioned, this behaviour is by design (one that I happen to strongly disagree with, as can be seen from the links from Victor's post). To make matters worse, a post that's been community-wikied in this way is not easy to reverse: you'd have to reverse both the question _and_ each answer, one by one. I know this because I had to do this recently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the question unfortunately was automatically forced to be community wiki when it reached 60 answers. This mechanism exists in most SE sites to avoid reputation farming. But codegolf is different and this rule does not makes sense here, the auto community wiki in codegolf is a major annoyance.

See these questions:

- [Auto CW limit (number of answers)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29/auto-cw-limit-number-of-answers)
- [Should golf questions be a CW and why?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/should-golf-questions-be-a-cw-and-why)
- [Remove Auto CW Limit](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/713/remove-auto-cw-limit)
- [Please raise or remove CW limits on Code Golf SE site](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238/please-raise-or-remove-cw-limits-on-code-golf-se-site)

Specially, see this answer:

- https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33/3755

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thank you for the tip.  Nice question you posted!  My answer was number 82 four hours ago, there are 90 now!

Comment: Nick Craver has moved the answer limit up again, to 500: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238/please-raise-or-remove-cw-limits-on-code-golf-se-site#comment2859_242